# Error : The template's contents do not follow the schema

Tags: c#, .net, svg, schema

I have a SVG document defined as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<svg width="210mm" height="297mm"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" dominant-baseline="hanging">
<text x="108.18mm" y="7.14mm" font-size="12pt" font-family="Times New Roman" font-weight="bold" font-style="italic">SVG Template to Test Various Styling</text>
<style>
    text {
      fill: gold;
      stroke: maroon;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
 </style>
</svg>
```

While this SVG gets Previewed in the browser as expected when I pass this on to a C# appilcation which is built to read svgs if throws an exception saying **`

> The template's contents do not follow the schema

`** .

I have no Idea as to what is causing this as the browser seems to be rendering this as expected

Further the error also says :- The element 'svg' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' has invalid child element 'style' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'

Any idea that may help me ?

Comment: What application? How does it load the SVG?

Comment: Hi Robert 
This is a custom application and I'm not sure how it works unfortunately . The error also says :- The element 'svg' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' has invalid child element 'style' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'

Comment: I don't think we can help you debug an unknown application. The application looks broken at first glance.

Comment: Is it the case that the namespace  'w3.org/2000/svg' doesn't support style tag ?

Comment: It does, so the application is likely buggy.

Comment: The SVG schema is very specific about what tags are allowed.  Style is not a tag that is in the schema.

Comment: @jdweng where can I see what tags are allowed ? Is it defined somewhere

Comment: I found schema on web (https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-SVG11-20020108/SVG.xsd)  I'm looking to see what is wrong.

Comment: @jdweng [style is an SVG tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/styling.html#StyleElementhttps://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/styling.html#StyleElement) and is allowed by the SVG schema.

Comment: Yes, but there are required attributes : <complexType name="styleType" mixed="true">
<attributeGroup ref="svg:stdAttrs"/>
<attribute ref="xml:space" fixed="preserve"/>
<attribute name="type" type="svg:ContentTypeType" use="required"/>
<attribute name="media" type="svg:MediaDescType" use="optional"/>
<attribute name="title" type="string" use="optional"/>
</complexType>

Comment: @jdweng type is [optional in SVG 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html). The rest were optional anyway.

Comment: But the OP is using Style and getting an error because of missing attributes.